# Why does accessing another model attribute in an appended attribute of a model cause a "possible infinite loop"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My **Laravel 9** application has two models: A `brand` model and a `product` model. Each `product` belongs to one `brand` and one `brand` has many `products` (1:n relation). The `product` model should offer a "calculated" (appended) attribute called `title_medium`, that concatenates the title of the brand and the title of the product on request.

As soon as I try to access `$this->brand` in the `getTitleMediumAttribute()` method of the product model, `xdebug` throws a `possible infinite loop` exception and cancels execution (after N iterations). I think it has something to do with relations and loading sequences (eager loading), but I couldn´t find a solution so far.

### The brand model

The `brand` model has an attribute `title` and has many `products` which belong to a `brand`.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Brand extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Additional attributes for this model
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'prices'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($brand) {
            $brand->slug = Str::slug($brand->title, '-', 'de');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Returns all products for a brand
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

### The product model

Each `product` belongs to a `brand`. An appended attribute `title_medium` should concatenate the brand title and the product title.

```
namespace App\Models;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Searchable, Filterable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'brand_id',
        'image'
    ];

    /**
     * Additional attributes for this model
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'title_long',
        'lowest_price',
        'highest_discount_percent_price',
        'latest_price_date',
        'price_count'
    ];

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($product) {
            $product->slug = Str::slug($product->title_long, '-', 'de');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Product belongs to one brand
     */
    public function brand(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the combined title from product and brand
     */
    public function getTitleMediumAttribute(): string
    {
        // THIS CAUSES A "POSSIBLE INFINITE LOOP EXCEPTION" in xdebug
        return $this->brand->title . ' ' . $this->title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these the entire models, or is some code being omitted for posting on SO? Specifically other `$appends` or `$with` attributes on the `Brand` class could be causing issues like these.

Comment: Yes, I´ve shortened them for SO. I´ve updated attributes in my question above.

Comment: Does the `prices` attribute on `Brand` reference the `products` relation?

Comment: Yes, you can find the **prices()** method at the end of the __Brand__ class. It´s a __hasMany__ relation to __Price__.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [Attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead of `getTitleMediumAttribute`, like this and tell me if you still get the same error (use this method instead of `getTitleMediumAttribute):

```php
public function titleMedium(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::get(
        fn () => "{$this->brand->title} $this->title",
    );
}
```

`Attribute` is `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute`

Comment: I´ve tried but it has the same effect: As soon as I try to access the brand title via $this->brand->title the "possible infinite loop" exception is thrown...

Comment: Fetching the brand object manually works, but that´s not the sense of having a relation I would say :D

    protected function titleLong(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: function () {
                $brand = Brand::find($this->brand_id);
                return $brand->title . ' ' . $this->title;
            }

        );
    }